# Tkinter row and column placement

Tags: python, tkinter

The button and label defined in this script remain at the top left regardless of the row or column I specify. Could anyone give me a hint on why? Thanks for your time.

```
## Login Script

from tkinter import *
import hashlib

class Login:

    def __init__(self,master):

        ## Create frame
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=4)
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=4)
        print(self.frame.grid_size())

        ## Create Login
        username_label = Label(self.frame,text="Username:")
        username_label.grid(row=0,column=2,columnspan=2)
        self.username = Entry(self.frame)
        self.username.grid(row=1,column=2,columnspan=2)
        self.username.focus_set()



def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400+400+150")
    app = Login(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default empty columns have size 0. You can use keyword `minsize` in function `grid_columnconfigure` to adjust the minimal size of a column. `weight` only defines how much space is distributed if the window is expanded by the user. Following example sets the minimal size of column 1 to 100.

```
self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=4, minsize =100)
```

You can adjust this to your needs.